# The effect of the second await in an asynchronous function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

In the following program:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void action(string s)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    static async Task f()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => action("3"));
        await Task.Run(() => action("4"));
        // action("4");
    }
    static async void g()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        await f();
        Console.WriteLine("5");
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        g();
        Console.WriteLine("2");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

If I replace:

```
 await Task.Run(() => action("4"));
```

with

```
 action("4");
```

the output does not change:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Is it correct that only the first await in an asynchronous function has a practical effect? Why should we use the second or third `await` inside one function?

Comment: Avoid `async void`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes I added `g` just to call `f`. Since `Main` cannot be async. an improvisation...

Comment: In C# 7.1 it is possible to define the Main method as Async and you can call _await g();_. And that will change everything in your test.

Comment: Check out the [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/) of the valid `Main` signatures. Also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void "Avoid async void") is the link that explains why `async void` methods should be avoided.

Comment: Describe 'practical'. You sample is too artificial, sometimes you want concurrent and sometimes sequential async.

Comment: @HenkHolterman practical means actual. Something that changes the output or significantly changes the performance. I'm asking what is the effect of a second `await` in a single function. Why a method allows multiple awaits when only the first one has an actual effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you expect the two `await`s being done in `f` to run concurrently, and it's a common mistake to think that asynchronicity is the same as concurrency, but it's not. Let me do a step-by-step of what's going on in the code.

1. The asynchronous method `g` is invoked through `g();`.
2. `Thread.Sleep(100)` puts the thread to sleep for 100ms.
3. `1` is written to the console.
4. The asynchronous method `f` is invoked through `await f();`.
5. A task is scheduled to be run by a Thread Pool thread and asked to run `action("3")`.
6. The asynchronous wait in step 5 makes `f` return the control to the caller (`g`).
7. The asynchronous wait in step 4 makes `g` return the control to the caller (`Main`).
8. `2` is written to the console.
9. At some point between steps 6-8, `action("3")` *likely* started running, or it will start soon.
10. `action("3")` waits 100ms, prints `3` to the console and waits another 100ms.
11. The control is returned to `f` which schedules `action("4")` to be run by another Thread Pool thread.
12. Same as step 10 happens, but printing `4`.
13. `f` finishes execution, returning the control to `g` after the `await`.
14. `g` prints `5` to the console.

As you can see, changing step 11 to not schedule `action("4")` and instead running it in the current thread would not change the flow of the program, as `g` would still have to wait until `f` finishes.

Notice that this all means that there's no benefit to having the second `await` in `f`, but that's just because the example is not a good one. If this was an API or an application with a main UI thread, it would actually be beneficial to have that second `await`, provided it was to do something actually asynchronous or CPU-intensive.

Comment: So the second `await` is useless? Does it have a practical effect? I can remove the second, third, fourth,... `awaits` and nothing changes.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus It's useless, but because the example is not at all good to understand the benefits of `async` and `await`. If this was an ASP.NET Core application with real asynchronous operations, the benefits would very much be there, same as if it was a UI application as you'd avoid blocking the UI thread

Comment: Can you give me a console program in which a second `await` is useful and has practical effects? I could not write such a program...

Comment: @MinimusHeximus Console programs are probably the ones that benefits the least from async/await, and only more advanced cases can actually benefit from that model, but it's not really easy to come up with an example

Comment: @MinimusHeximus here is an example: you start a `Task<DataTable>` at the start of your program, and later you just `await` this single task anytime you need this `DataTable`, till the end of the program. You don't have to worry whether the task has completed or not. The `await` will take care of it. If the task is completed, you'll get the `DataTable` instantly, otherwise your code will wait until the task is completed. This is an example of caching an asynchronous resource.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Are you talking about a second `await` inside one async function in a Console Program? I know how a first `await` is useful. I need an example that shows how a second `await` inside an async function is useful.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus I am talking about a second `await` on the same `Task` in general, independently of the location or the type of the app. About a second `await` on the same `Task` inside the same method, it's more difficult to think of a meaningful example. Maybe you could have a reason to `await` it once inside a `try` block and suppress the exception, and later in the same method `await` it once again without error handling, and let the exception propagate.